# TypeError: Datetime subtraction can only be applied to datetime series

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark-pandas

I am trying to replace pandas with pyspark.pandas library, when I tried this :
pdf is a pyspark.pandas dataframe

```
pdf["date_diff"] = pdf["date1"] - pdf["date2"]
```

I got the below error :

```
File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\pyspark\pandas\data_type_ops\datetime_ops.py", line 75, in sub
raise TypeError("Datetime subtraction can only be applied to datetime series.")
```

TypeError: Datetime subtraction can only be applied to datetime series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the the column values to a date time value

```
pdf['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(pdf['date1'])
pdf['date2'] = pd.to_date_time(pdf['date2'])
```